# Can I create a method-scoped constant in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, oop, constants

I want to create a constant that is accessible only inside its containing method.  In other languages one might do this:

```c
void function()
{
  const int MAX = 25;
  int array[MAX];

  //DO SOMETHING
}
void function2()
{
   const int MAX = 50;
   int array[MAX];
   //DO SOMETHING ELSE
}
```

In both methods `MAX` is not global to the class.  I believe in data hiding, and I'd like to know if there is a way to do this in Ruby.  Can we create constants inside a method?

Comment: I would question why you would need to do this. Surely if you are creating it inside a method, you could simply create a variable in the method that you never modify?

Comment: It makes it much easier to read code when a value is known to be constant.  I see MAX and I know its constant.  I see max and I think it's calculated.  My co-worker sees my code 6 months after I leave for greener pastures, and knows my intent.

Comment: @baash05, just something weird, what about dynamic constants? i improved my answer on that. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that. The problem is not about whether or not a constant is private. Ruby prohibits creation of a constant in a method definition.

```
def foo
  Foo = :foo
end
# => SyntaxError: ... dynamic constant assignment
```

Comment: what about assigning constants in runtime via class_eval ?

Comment: @JeslyVarghese That is possible. But that will not help.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can’t, but even if you could there wouldn’t be much point because constants in Ruby aren’t really constant:

```
MY_CONST = 'foo'
MY_CONST << 'bar'
MY_CONST  #=> 'foobar'
MY_CONST = 'baz' # warning: already initialized constant MY_CONST
```

If you’re worried about the object itself being modified (rather than the reference, which makes more sense if you’re returning the object), then you may wish to [`freeze`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-freeze) the object to prevent it from being mutated (though note that it’s a shallow freeze, for deep freezing, see [IceNine](https://github.com/dkubb/ice_nine)).

Answer (score 1):

Going a bit oxymoron and the idea is lot a weird, what about dynamic constants?

```
class FOO
  def method
    method_constant :METHOD_CONSTANT, 25
    METHOD_CONSTANT
  end
  def method_constant(constant_name, value)
    constant_name.to_s.slice!(0,1) 
    FOO.class_eval "#{constant_name} = #{value}"
    FOO.class_eval "private_constant :#{constant_name}"
  end
  private :method_constant
end

f = FOO.new
f.method #:=>25
FOO::METHOD_CONSTANT #:=>error
```

Well, these constants will be available out of the scope of method in which it is defined. One thing am not sure if about is, how many laws of OOPS on constant this going to break!

Comment: You can have private constants, but they’re, of course, scoped within another constant, not within a method like the OP wants.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: Wow! new to me. Can you explain it further deep. **scoped within another constant** is confusing me. So does it go as long as you have a an object as a constant which encapsulate the constant you want as private?

Comment: Given `module A; module B; end; private_constant :B; end`, `A::B` can only be referenced when within the scope of `A`.

Comment: Ha!! yea i am wrong!! missed out private_constant method. Thanks.. :)

Comment: Yeah I have private modules inside my class, and it accomplishes it through the class... but in an effort to be a better oop coder I thought it might be good to engage more data hiding

Comment: Using the values directly isn't a real problem.  I was looking for a bit cleaner code, and figured this would be a nice addition.  I will go with variables, though because direct values always smell bad to me.

Comment: Well since all ruby versions of constants seem to break OOP.. I think you're safe :D and funny as.